# Replace Value in column based on another column With R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I'm trying to replace the value of a column based on the data in a different column, but it's not working.  Here's some example data.

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = 1:10,
                 Col2 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d"),
                 Col3 = c("11%", "12%", "13%", "14%", "15%", "16%", "17%", "18%", "19%", "20%"))
```

If the value of Col2 is b, I need to change the value of Col3 to NA or 0 (NA is more accurate, but for what I'm doing, a 0 will also work).  Column 3 is percents, I know I used strings here.

I tried doing this a few ways, most recently of which is the loop I have listed below.  I'm open to any solution on this though. Is my loop not working because I'm not defining a pattern?

```
for(i in df){
  if(df$Col2 == "b"){
    str_replace(df$Col3, replacement = NA)
  }
}

print(df)
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a `base R` solution:

```
df$Col3[df$Col2 == 'b'] <- NA
```

Here's a `dplyr/tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)    

df %>% mutate(Col3 = ifelse(Col2 == 'b',NA_character_,Col3))
```

(Original, but less efficient `case_when` solution)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Col3 = case_when(Col2 == 'b' ~ NA_character_,
                          TRUE ~ Col3))
```

This gives us:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1     1    a  11%
2     2    a  12%
3     3    a  13%
4     4    b <NA>
5     5    b <NA>
6     6    c  16%
7     7    c  17%
8     8    d  18%
9     9    d  19%
10   10    d  20%
```

Comment: Although I've been using `dplyr` for years, I haven't seen `case_when()` before. Thanks for sharing. Not as intuitive for a beginner as `ifelse()` but still super handy to know about.

Comment: No problem! I edited to `ifelse` right when you did, which is definitely more efficient.

Comment: Probably better to use dplyrs `if_else` instead of `ifelse`, to ensure that the data type of b is retained

Answer (score 1):

A base `dplyr` solution, using `ifelse()` instead of `case_when()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Col1 = 1:10,
                 Col2 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d"),
                 Col3 = seq(.11, .2, by = .1))

df %>%
  mutate(Col3 = ifelse(Col2 == 'b', NA, Col2))
```

Answer (score 0):

pkpto39,

Try this:

```
library('tidyverse')
df <- data.frame(Col1 = 1:10,
                 Col2 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d")
                 Col3 = c("11%", "12%", "13%", "14%", "15%", "16%", "17%", "18%", "19%", "20%"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- df %>% mutate(Col3 = ifelse(Col2 == "b", NA, Col3))
```